# Error al conectar con Instancia Sql en Windows Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

Tengo problemas para conectar una instancia Sql en un windows server 2008 r2, ya tenia algunas conexiones con mis aplicaciones Access y C# e inclusive podia conectarme con Remote Desktop desde mi PC al servidor, pero ahora no puedo conectarme por ninguna via remota o con mis conexiones usando ODBC.

Tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ODBC:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya reinicie los servicios, intente conectarme con diferentes usuarios, sa, admin y con ninguno obtengo exito.

Si hay comunicacion entre los equipos los ping llegan sin problemas, alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema?

Cuando hago ping al servidor lo hago con la IP por default que el servidor tiene, pero me ha dado cuenta cuando hago ping con el nombre del servidor este tiene otra IP, aunque d igual forma no la puedo conectar, a que se deberá?

Este es el error desde SSMS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos.

Comment: Has probado usando sqlcmd o ssms para conectarse a esa misma instancia de BD desde la máquina que intentas usar ODBC? Que RDP funcione es irrelevante

Comment: Si, tambien lo intente sin exito.
@Alfabravo